# Windows 8.1 App C# XAML help: Show message if no radio buttons are selected

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm trying to code my ESurvey application. I have a list of radio buttons. Here is the code on SurveyPage1.xaml:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="-10,10,10,-10">
        <TextBlock Text="PARLIAMENT VISITOR CENTRE SURVEY" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="48" Margin="100,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBlock Text="1. How would you describe your overall visit experience?" Margin="100,100,0,0" FontSize="18"/>
        <RadioButton Name="radioExcellent" Content="Excellent" Margin="100,10,0,0" FontSize="12"/>
        <RadioButton Name="radioGood" Content="Good" Margin="100,10,0,0" FontSize="12"/>
        <RadioButton Name="radioAverage" Content="Average" Margin="100,10,0,0" FontSize="12"/>
        <RadioButton Name="radioPoor" Content="Poor" Margin="100,10,0,0" FontSize="12"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Button Name="nextButton1" Content="Next" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1250,525,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="#FFED2E38" Click="Button_S1_S2"/>
```

And my SurveyPage1.xaml.cs:

```
private void Button_S1_S2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Frame != null)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SurveyPage2));
        }
    }
```

What I want to do is that if no radio button is checked, it will not proceed to the next page(clicking nextButton1 would show an error saying "Please enter an option.")

Can someone help me on this? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just check the `IsChecked` property of all the `RadioButton`s in a nextButton1 click handler:

```
private async void Button_S1_S2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (radioExcellent.IsChecked != true && radioGood.IsChecked != true && radioAverage.IsChecked != true && radioPoor.IsChecked != true)
    {
        MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog("Please rate the content before proceeding!");
        await md.ShowAsync();
    }
    else
    {
         if (this.Frame != null)
         {
              this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SurveyPage2));
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I am getting this error however

    Error 1 The type or namespace name 'MessageDialog' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I'm not sure where to edit the click handler...

Comment: Try adding `using Windows.UI.Popups;` in your code behind file

Comment: Yep! It works now, but regardless of the message popup, it still redirects to the next page...

Comment: Edited, just put the rest of the handler in the `else` block

Comment: Yep! Worked like a charm. Thanks so much again!

Answer (score 0):

In the click event handler for the next button, you check if some of the radiobuttons are set